# Reactjs change the state of an object's property based on checked input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and am building a simple todo list.  I have this object in my `initialState`

```
 getInitialState:function(){
    return {
        items: [
            {
                text:"Buy Fish",
                key: "1",
                done: 0
            }
            ]
        }
 },
```

My TodoList component has this map function

```
var listItem = this.props.items.map((item, index)=>{
        return <li key={item.key}> <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>{this.props.onChange(item.key, e)}} /> <span onClick={()=>{this.props.editItem(item.text)}}>{item.text}</span> <button onClick={()=>this.props.removeItem(item.key)}>x</button> </li>
    });
```

Now I want to click on the checkbox and change the state of the property `done` to 1.

The onChange prop is leading to a function

```
  itemDone:function(index, e){
  var myArray = this.state.items;
  var a = e.target.checked;
  console.log(index);
},
```

What is the correct way to change the value from 0 to 1 to that specific item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index to your `onChange` method.

```
var listItem = this.props.items.map((item,index)=>{
            return <li key={item.key}> <input type="checkbox" onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChange(index,e)} /> <span onClick={()=>{this.props.editItem(item.text)}}>{item.text}</span> <button onClick={()=>this.props.removeItem(item.key)}>x</button> </li>
        });
```

and get specific items with and `index`:

```
itemDone:function(index,e){
    var myArray = this.state.items;
    var a = e.target.checked;
    console.log('item': this.state.items[index]);
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index and then edit the same object. Also make use of `spread operator` to create a new object instance of the item array otherwise, `myArray` will refer to the immutable object state item itself.

```
var listItem = this.props.items.map((item, index)=>{
            return <li key={item.key}> <input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>this.props.onChange(index)} /> <span onClick={()=>{this.props.editItem(item.text)}}>{item.text}</span> <button onClick={()=>this.props.removeItem(item.key)}>x</button> </li>
        });


itemDone:function(index){
    var myArray = [...this.state.items];
    if(myArray[index].done == 0) {
          myArray[index].done = 1; 
    } else {
          myArray[index].done = 0; 
     }
    this.setState({items: myArray})
 },
```